# Integrating Salesforce with Wordpress using Force.com Sites

Tags: force.com-sites

I'm using Force.com sites to integrate Wordpress and Salesforce.

I've created a VF page called Subscriber with information like Name, Email, Zip. I've added this into an iframe in a Wordpress site. I need to pass additional information from the Wordpress site (i.e. Product to which the user is subscribing) to VF page and then save it as a Salesforce Contact Information to be saved is Name, Email, Zip, Product. How do I do this?

(The issue is I'll have multiple products to which a user can subscribe to and I can't create different VF pages to include into Wordpress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can pass data into an iframe from a page on a separate domain is through the querystring parameters on the iFrame tag. Your Visualforce page can then pull down the params and use accordingly. You can't pass data from the container into the frame using JavaScript because you are subject to same origin policy.